# Where do function definitions live? In the stack or in the heap?

Tags: javascript, function, stack, heap-memory, definition

When we define a function, where does it go in terms of memory partitions? On the stack like primitive data types? Or on the heap like objects?

Answer (score 2):

Functions are objects. Therefore, the function’s identifier is in the stack, and the function’s value is stored in the heap.

Comment: A function creates an activation object when it's called. Before that it's just a text. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I’m not sure of the difference between an activation object and an execution context, but from what I know, I’d agree with that first statement — I’d change the phrasing: a function call creates an execution context. What do you mean by “just a text”?

Comment: [They are the same thing](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clIRExSc)
By just a text I mean a chain of characters (string)

Comment: During the creation phase (before a function is invoked), variable declarations (functions included) are hoisted and stored in the variable environment object